# Makefile for a Linux kernel module with multiple sub-directories

Tags: linux, makefile, linux-kernel

I need help regarding the Makefile for a kernel module. Even examples would be of great help.

Currently my module code is under multiple directories. Let us say

```
<MAIN-DIR> --- l2.c 
    <SUB-DIR1> --- hello.c
    <SUB-DIR2> --- bye.c
```

For the above scenario how can I code my makefile. Because for building l2 module I need l2.o hello.o and bye.o. And currently they are in multiple directories.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're building a module out of the kernel tree, a simple makefile like the following should work:

```
MODULE_NAME = mymodule

SRC     := foo.c src/bar.c

# Path to target Linux Kernel
KDIR        := $(shell pwd) # <--- Fill in with path to kernel you're compiling against

$(MODULE_NAME)-objs = $(SRC:.c=.o)

obj-m       := $(MODULE_NAME).o
PWD     := $(shell pwd)

EXTRA_CFLAGS := -I$(PWD)/src -I$(PWD)/include

all:
    $(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) M=$(PWD) modules
```

As can be seen in the `SRC :=` line, you simple specify the paths to all of your source files, including those in subdirectories.  The top level kernel makefile in `KDIR` will take care of the compilation.

Further information about the kernel build system and out of tree builds can be found in the kernel source documentation in `Documentation/kbuild/modules.txt`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but seems its not working out for me. Problem is .c file in <SUB_DIR1> is including headers in <SUB_DIR2> .. So when I run the makefile it says its not able to access the header files which are included using " "

Comment: I've updated the example.  You can use EXTRA_CFLAGS to pass additional flags to the compiler such as extra include directories.  Having something in <SUB_DIR2> include a header from <SUB_DIR1> without specifying the directory seems a bit odd.  It would be normal to group the includes in a directory and reference them from there, possibly with a `EXTRA_CFLAGS := -I$(PWD)/include` clause in the Makefile.

Comment: Hoo thanks. One more small doubt. I have modified the kernel to include a new function and declared it in EXPORT_SYMBOL. Now I am calling that function from my .c file. When I compile I get error saying implicit declaration .. Ideally it should be taken care at the linking time right not at .o creation time right

Comment: If you've exported a symbol, you should also include its declaration as an extern in one of the linux kernel header files.  This header file should subsequently be #included by your .c module source.  You shouldn't rely on implicit declarations.

Comment: What about functions which are included from other .c files in the same module. Actually I have a function which i decalred in l2.h and defined in l2.c. Now I am using the function in hello.c and bye.c and even including the header file l2.h. But when .ko file is generated it says the function as undefined

Comment: With the setup above there shouldn't be any compiler warnings when compiling hello.c and bye.c as l2.h is #included, so no implicit declaration warnings.  If you're getting function undefined, that sounds like a linker error, with l2.o (which contains the definition of your function) not being included in the final object.  When running the make, use `make V=1` to turn on verbose output to show where the error lies.